# Wrong destination size for strncpy

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32, sizeof, strncpy

Visual Studio Code 1.73.1, PlatformIO 6.1.5, toolchain-xtensa-esp32 8.4.0.
In a third-party library there are these lines of [code](https://github.com/khoih-prog/ESPAsync_WiFiManager/blob/master/examples/Async_ConfigOnSwitch/Async_ConfigOnSwitch.ino#L1003):

```
#define TZNAME_MAX_LEN 50
#define TIMEZONE_MAX_LEN 50

typedef struct
{
    WiFi_Credentials WiFi_Creds[NUM_WIFI_CREDENTIALS];
    char TZ_Name[TZNAME_MAX_LEN]; 
    char TZ[TIMEZONE_MAX_LEN];    
    uint16_t checksum;
} WM_Config;

WM_Config WM_config;

// ...

String tempTZ = ESPAsync_wifiManager.getTimezoneName();

if (strlen(tempTZ.c_str()) < sizeof(WM_config.TZ_Name) - 1) 
    strcpy(WM_config.TZ_Name, tempTZ.c_str());
else
    strncpy(WM_config.TZ_Name, tempTZ.c_str(), sizeof(WM_config.TZ_Name) - 1);
```

`sizeof(WM_config.TZ_Name) - 1` evaluates to 49.
But the compiler returns this warning:

> 'char* strncpy(char*, const char*, size_t)' writing 49 bytes into a region of size 32 overflows the destination [-Wstringop-overflow=]

I don't understand why it thinks the destination has a size of 32 bytes, while it is 50 bytes long, actually.

Comment: What is `String` and where does it come from?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/

Comment: Three things: First of all why not `tempTZ.length()` instead of `strlen(tempTZ.c_str())`? Secondly, your current call to `strncpy` will *not* add the string terminator. Thirdly, why the size check at all? It's not needed, as `strncpy` will stop at the string null-terminator in the source string just like `strcpy`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I agree with you but it's not my code. There a link to the git repository of this library. My question is about where the 32 comes from.

Comment: Perhaps a decimal versus hexadecimal mixup somewhere? Hexadecimal `0x32` is decimal `50`. The original author perhaps wrote `32` by mistake when she or he was planning to write `0x32`? You have to look through the code more. And if possible ask the original author, or possibly submit a bug report.

Comment: Maybe a compiler bug? What happens if you copy to `&WM_config.TZ_Name[0]` or even store the pointer in a `char*` variable and use that for the copy?

Comment: There are a lot of bugs in bugzilla around this warning. e.g. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=94335 https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92955... and a lot more...

Comment: Can't reproduce. A toolchain bug?